# Powercli to set "Autostart" on VM on ESXI not working

Tags: virtual-machine, powercli, autostart, esxi

*I am using versions:*

`ESXI 6.5.0 Update 3 (Build 14990892)`

`Power CLI VMware PowerCLI 11.0.0 build 10380590.`

*I have a VM* that I am importing (ISO) into an ESXI and trying to set **Autostart** on the VM to "enabled" programmatically via some scripts, but it is ***not working***. I am using the powercli command:

```
Set-VMHostStartPolicy (Get-VMHost | Get-VMHostStartPolicy) -Enabled:$true
```

I've also tried some variants of this command but none seem to work. I see the "event" get logged as "Reconfigure Autostart" under the "Recent Tasks" menu on the ESXI Web GUI as soon as I input the command, so its definitely configurating something, but when I double-check the state of the VM to see if **Autostart** is enabled, it *still* lists "Enable" as an option, implying Autostart is *NOT* enabled. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Can anyone help me please? I just want to have this VM start automatically incase there is a power outage or server crash; But only in these cases, I want it to import powered OFF for the first time (as you can see in screen shot the EPS VM is imported but in a powered down state, which is what I want)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing is setting the host's default policy... You would think that would work. I'm using this code on ESXi 7.0 Update 1 to set the guest's policy:

```
$vmstartpolicy = Get-VM "$vm_name" | Get-VMStartPolicy
Set-VMStartPolicy -StartPolicy $vmstartpolicy -StartAction PowerOn
```

It has the same issue that it doesn't show in the web UI, (which somebody will complain about, and I'll have to fix) but it does auto-start the VM after a reboot, so at least it's a start (pun not intended).

Edit: After playing around a bit, I managed to find a solution that updates the UI.

```
plink -batch -ssh $user@$IP -l "$user" -pw "$password" vim-cmd hostsvc/autostartmanager/update_autostartentry "`$(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep `"$vm_name`" | awk '{print `$1}')" "PowerOn" 0 1 "systemDefault" "systemDefault" "systemDefault"
```

Using plink to ssh into the host and run this vim-cmd, it updates the UI properly. Take note of the back-ticks (`) to escape the dollar signs (except the one with the $vm_name variable) and quotes in the sub command, so that powershell doesn't try to interpret them before sending them through the ssh tunnel. All the sub command does is get the all the VMs, use grep to filter down to the output line with the vm_name you specify, and use awk to print only the 1st column (the vm id required for the outer vim-cmd).